# Passing query objects in Laravel by reference

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, query-builder

This is for Laravel 5.2. I'm not sure what the difference is between these two segments of code, but one seems to work by reference and the other doesn't.

In this example, the query object retains none of the modifications from the method call, which forces me to check for false to perform an action:

```
$query = new User();
$query = $this->processOrderByFields($query, $request, User::getOrderByFields());

if ($query === false) {
    return $this->respondError(HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}

public function processOrderByFields($query, $request, $availableFields)
{
    # Get fields

    foreach ($fields as $field) {

        # Do things to the field...

        if ( # Not important ) {
            $query = $query->orderBy(# Field, # Direction);
        } else {
            $badFields[] = $field;
        }
    }

    if ($badFields) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $query;
    }
}
```

However, this works fine:

```
$query = new User();
$this->processInclude($query, $request, Client::getIncludeRelationships());

public function processInclude($query, $request, $objectRelationship )
{
    if ( $request->get('include') && is_array($request->get('include')) ) {
        $include = array_intersect($request->get('include'), $objectRelationship);
        foreach($include as $relation) {
            $query->with($relation);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the relationship building part of the `with` method, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had checked this before I posted, but the answer seems to lie in how the methods interact with both the container and the parent object:

In `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`:

```
public static function with($relations)
{
    if (is_string($relations)) {
        $relations = func_get_args();
    }

    $instance = new static;

    return $instance->newQuery()->with($relations);
}
```

In `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`:

```
public function orderBy($column, $direction = 'asc')
{
    $property = $this->unions ? 'unionOrders' : 'orders';
    $direction = strtolower($direction) == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';

    $this->{$property}[] = compact('column', 'direction');

    return $this;
}
```

---

So, `with` creates a new static instance of a query (I'm not sure what this means, but the overall effect seems to be that it persists after the method returns) while orderBy must be chained. This confirms my experience, but the nuance of the `with` method escapes me.

**Edit:**

So the second method actually did NOT work! I didn't realize it until I tried calling an endpoint with only a relationship include query parameter passed instead of that parameter plus others. Apparently, the static instance in the `with` class has to be passed around (`$query = $query->...`) the same way as the other query chains.

I hope this helps someone because I've been stuck on this for several hours.